# Roboflow dropping cyrillic labeled objects when creating dataset version

Tags: roboflow

I have my russian license plate symbols classification dataset labeled from scratch. While labeling, there was no problem in naming classes with cyrillic letters. Everything is showing correctly in "health check" tab. However, when I try to create a new version, all objects of cyrillic named classes are being implicitly dropped. And when I say implicitly, I mean that actual amount of images in training set is less than amount stated in "training set" tab(4202 actual vs 7102 stated), the same with validation and test.
I've tried:

- Creating dataset with augmentation and only dropping "res" dummy class and augmentation
- The same but with remapping all cyrillic to latin
- No augmentation with dropping only res
- No augmentation no dropping
- Dropping all classes

And result (except augmentation) was always the same.

[Actual last image of training set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SZsG.png)

[Stated amount of images in the training set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxzI4.png)

[Roboflow has "dropped" all the 23 classes, but images are still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1e3r.png)

[Health check tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1Jiu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up dropping non ascii chars. I went ahead and shared this UX with the team as its something that can be addressed in the labeling process

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already started relabeling with Selenium, everything seems to work fine after switching to ascii only.